# Code error when working at environment hosting

Tags: php

i am not PHP expert , i uploaded code below to my host , **it working well on Xampp but error on hosting environment :**

> " syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '{' " at line 5 it mean
>   "lass SyncAjax {

```
<?php
    if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

    if (!class_exists('SyncAjax')){
        class SyncAjax {
```

> code error here

```
            public static $AJAX_SYNC_OFFER_TRIGGER_ID       = AFFILIATE_PROMOTIONS_PREFIX.'sync_offer_trigger';

            public static $AJAX_SYNC_PROMOTION_TRIGGER_ID   = AFFILIATE_PROMOTIONS_PREFIX.'sync_promotion_trigger';
            public static $AJAX_SYNC_FULL_TRIGGER_ID        = AFFILIATE_PROMOTIONS_PREFIX.'sync_full_trigger';

            .........................
```

Comment: post your full code

Comment: Check your open parenthesis and close parenthesis

Comment: Post more code so we can help